# "wmic memorychip get | clip" in cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

Hello i am not able to run this command:

```
wmic memorychip get | clip
```

This command does not returns any output or error.

I am using windows 7.

Kindly tell me what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Check your clipboard...?

Comment: We have already written once that `| clip` results in a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) of the UTF-16 Little Endian encoded output of `%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe` (Unicode output) from handle __STDOUT__ (standard output) to handle __STDIN__ (standard input) of `%SystemRoot%\System32\clip.exe` which copies the output of `wmic` to the Windows clipboard. Run just `wmic memorychip get` in [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) to get the output displayed in the console window.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `clip /?` and read the short output help. Then run one after the other `wmic /?`, `wmic memorychip /?`, `wmic memorychip get /?` and read each output help carefully and completely. See also the Microsoft documentation for the [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) and [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Comment: PS: Windows command processor `cmd.exe` and its successor PowerShell `powershell.exe` are two completely different interpreters which is very important on using `wmic` which outputs text always as Unicode encoded character stream. PowerShell is a full Unicode aware application, but not Windows command processor. You should never tag a question with `powershell` __and__ with `cmd` because those two interpreters are completely different. You should know if you open a __cmd__ or a __PowerShell__ window. A PowerShell window is by default with blue background and command prompt starts with `PS`.

Comment: As other's have said the output is redirected to clip.exe to show the output on console use `wmic memorychip`,but i prefer not to use it because it will show the output really messed up.i suggest to echo the output in a file (`i.e:wmic memorychip>>output.txt`)

Comment: use the batch file below for task automation.

Answer (score 1):

This happens, as the output is piped to [clip.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/clip). In other words, the output is there, but is sent to clipboard instead of printing it into the console.

As a side note, consider using [Set-Clipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-7.1) instead of `clip.exe`, if you have Powershell 5.1 or newer.

If there's a need to send output to clipboard and see it too, use [Tee-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-7.1) like so,

```
wmic memorychip get | tee-object -variable foo | set-clipboard; $foo
```

Answer (score 0):

As vonPryz answered that the ouput is there but  is redirected to clip.exe(A program that redirects output of command line tools to the Windows clipboard).but as you have described that you have windows 7,vonPryz solution won't work.you can use `wmic memorychip` to show output on console but it will mess up the output. you should echo the output in a file to see it(i.e`wmic memorychip >>output.txt`) or use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
wmic memorychip >>output.txt
notepad output.txt
pause >nul
```